# Splitting a list dependent of contents

Tags: list, haskell

I would like to create a function that turns this list into a new list of lists splitting this one each time it says "gap"

```
["dash", "dot", "dot", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dash", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dot", "gap"]
```

would become

```
[["dash", "dot", "dot"], ["dash", "dash", "dash"], ["dash", "dash", "dot"]]
```

any idea appreciated as lets say i have spent a lot of time on this with no luck...

```
format :: [String] -> [[String]]
format []
    = []
format (x:xs)
    | x == "gap" = []
    | otherwise = x : (format xs)

main :: IO()
main = 
    putStrLn ( show ( format ["dash", "dot", "dot", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dash", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dot", "gap"] ) )
```

This is what I've been working around but I'm getting caught up with type errors and even if I get them sorted I reckon it will only run until the first "gap"...

Comment: If you've spent a lot of time on the problem, why don't you try sharing what you have done? It'll help us believe that you've actually put effort into solving the problem and genuinely got stuck, instead of having come here to ask for a free coding service.

Comment: At least you came up with some function that did not do the job. So perhaps share the approach you took (a "conceptual algorithm" can be useful as well).

Comment: Sorry, just added that now

Comment: Hint: `Data.List` provides a function `break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`, such that `break (== "gap") ["dash", "dot", "dot", "gap", ...] == (["dash", "dot", "dot"], ["gap", ...])`

Comment: (You can use `Data.List.break`, or you can start by writing your own implementation to use in your definition of `format`.)

Comment: A suggestion for the situation when you get stuck: just look up some similar examples, and then you could figure out how to do it, e.g. if you check the sources for `words` or `lines` which are included in `Prelude`, you'll find what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`span` function does the job.

```
format :: [String] -> [[String]]
format ("gap":ws) = format ws
format [] = []
format ws = let (w1, w2) = span (/= "gap") ws
            in w1:format w2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `foldr` for this job

```
let fun = foldr (\l a -> case l of
                         "gap" -> [] : a
                         _     -> (l : (head a)) : (tail a)) []
Prelude> fun ["dash", "dot", "dot", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dash", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dot", "gap"]
[["dash","dot","dot"],["dash","dash","dash"],["dash","dash","dot"]]
```

If the current element `l` is a `"gap"` then lets insert a new empty list `[]` to the head of our accumulating list `a` or else lets take the `head` of our accumulating list `a`, insert the current element `l` to the `head` of our list and insert it to the `tail` of our accumulating list `a`.

The above method might introduce some blank sublists if there are consequtive `"gap"`s. So if that is a possibility then another approach could be.

```
let ff = filter (not . elem "gap") . groupBy (\x y -> x /= "gap" && y /= "gap")

Prelude> ff ["dash", "dot", "dot", "gap", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dash", "gap", "dash", "dash", "dot", "gap"]
[["dash","dot","dot"],["dash","dash","dash"],["dash","dash","dot"]]
```